# What does this rewrite rule do, if anything?

Tags: regex, iis, url-rewrite-module

Does this rule actually do anything? It looks like it just rewrites the url exactly the way it was already written to me. Am I missing something?

Trying to take steps to get rid of outbound rewrite rules and I'm puzzled what the purpose of this one even was.

```
      <rule name="Outbound clean rewrite catch other pages2" preCondition="IsHTML">
        <match filterByTags="A" pattern="^([_a-zA-z-0-9&amp;.%]+).aspx([_a-zA-z-0-9&amp;.%=?]*)$" />
        <action type="Rewrite" value="/{R:1}.aspx{R:2}" />
        <conditions>
          <add input="{URL}" pattern="\.axd$" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
      </rule>
```

Comment: A dot should be escaped in the pattern. Right now, it is just matching some URLs containing `aspx`. Also, `[A-z]` matches more than just ASCII letters. If you write it as `"^([_a-zA-Z-0-9&amp;.%]+)\.aspx([_a-zA-z-0-9&amp;.%=?]*)$"` it might work better.

Comment: Yup... I actually noticed that as I was posting this. So.. basically there are some edge cases where it would have unintended results b/c of that... clearly not the purpose of the rule though. If I fix that issue, then it looks like it does the same thing as if I just removed it altogether... nothing.

Comment: So, what is your question? Should you remove it or should you keep it? It is up to you. We can't help you unless you state clearly what you need to achieve.

Comment: @WiktorStribi As I mentioned, I want to remove it and I don't see any reason not to. But just doing a sanity check here to get some confirmation that I'm not crazy wondering why someone put this rule that does nothing in the project. I have minimal experience with both rewrite rules and regex so it wouldn't surprise me at all if there was something important this is doing that I just don't understand.

Comment: That 'amp' in the regex seems odd. Since the letters 'a','m','p' are already in the range 'a-z'.  Maybe a simplified regex like `^([^/].+)\.aspx(.*)$` would already be good enough?